# projectile that splits into two fragments of equal mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, momentum

I am studying for an exam, and this is  part of a problem in my book.

A projectile is launch from level ground and is intended to hit a target 100m away. Instead, it explodes into two fragments of equal mass, one of which lands 100m beyond the target. If the fragments don't take the same amount of time to land, must the second one land 100m short of the target?

The back of the book tells me that this isn't true, but I'm having a hard time figuring out why.

I know that the trajectory of the center of mass for the system is going to follow the trajectory of the projectile before it exploded. Thus, the CM of the system is at a distance of 100m from the origin. However, the equation for the center of mass would be $100 = mx_{cm} = \frac{1}{2}mx_1 + \frac{1}{2}mx_2$. Now $x_1 = 200$ by the conditions of the problem, so $ \implies x_2 = 0$. So clearly there must be some reason why this doesn't hold, but I can't figure it out.

Could anyone explain to me why this won't work?

Comment: There's two coordinates for each part of the bullet an $x$ coordinate and a $y$ coordinate. You've analyzed the $x$ coordinate, what do you know about $y$?

Comment: well the $y_{cm}$ coordinate would b $0$ since it is at ground level. So the $y$ coordinate for each part is also $0$, but I don't see how that is helpful.

I know momentum won't be conserved in the $y$ direction because of the presence of gravity acting on the system, but I can't see how to use that to my advantage

Comment: Saying that $y_{cm}=0$ is assuming the answer to the question. How do you know that $y_{cm}=0$ when $x_1=200{\rm m}$? I agree that IF you could prove that fact, then both bullets would hit the ground at the same time. But the problem actually assumes the bullets DON'T hit the ground at the same time. Also, the center of mass is still useful even if momentum isn't conserved...

Comment: To be a little less cryptic: make sure you are working at one given instant in time. Let's say the instant is when fragment 1 hits the ground, so $x_1=200{\rm m}$ and $y_1=0$. What can you say about $y_2$? $x_2$? $y_{cm}$? $x_{cm}$? I'll tell you that you can't say that $y_{cm}=0$. Also... it helps to imagine that $x_1$ doesn't actually stop when it hits the ground, but passes through (maybe there's a cliff at $150{\rm m}$ so the fragment passes $y=0$ without hitting anything).

Comment: So center of mass equations: $ x_{cm} = \frac{1}{2}x_1 + \frac{1}{2}x_2$ and $y_{cm} = \frac{1}{2}y_1 + \frac{1}{2}y_2 $.

If fragment 1 hits the ground, then $ x_{cm} = 100 + \frac{1}{2}x_2$ and $y_{cm} = \frac{1}{2}y_2 $. 

Since fragment 2 hasn't hit the ground yet I know $y_{cm} > 0$
and $ x_{cm} \leq 100$ so $x_2 < 0$

Comment: Yes, very good, that is basically right. Now the point is, what happens when $y_{cm}=0$? At that instant, you know that $x_{cm}=100$ (because the beauty of the center of mass is that it follows the original trajectory even though the bullet split into fragments). But where are $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2$? Fragment 2 hasn't landed yet... But we also know that $x_1>200$ (if we assume that fragment 1 went off a cliff, which simplifies things). So... what does that tell you about $x_2$?

Comment: So I guess that if $ x_1 > 200 $, then $x_2 < 0 $ still, but $ -100 < x_2 < 0$ so the fragments are not necessarily going to land the same distance away from the center of mass.